# Find the missing numbers in the magic square

Tags: no-computers, magic-square

The following is a magic square: each row, column and diagonal add to 34, all of the numbers 1 to 16 appear exactly once.  Find the missing numbers.

[image]

Comment: Whoever thinks this is easy - on the standard 4x4 magic square, either 1 and 8 or 1 and 3 are in the same row or column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this was not very difficult.

> [image]

Comment: Well done.  Is there any particular method you used or was it just trial-and-error?

Comment: @user2882061, there are methods to solve magic squares, triangles, stars, cubes etc.